# Can't send Email by AWS SES with serverless

Tags: serverless, amazon-ses

I can't send an Email by AWS SES with serverless， but it is working on localhost.

this is my serverless.yml

```
postSend:
handler: dist/src/handler/emailHandler.emailPost
events:
  - http:
      path: emailPost
      method: post
      cors: true
iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: "Allow"
    Action:
      - ses:SendEmail
    Resource: "*"
```

Comment: What's the error msg?

Comment: Please also add your email handler code.